# Dust.js streaming views using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, dust.js

I have a simple app that uses Express and [Hoffman](https://github.com/diffsky/hoffman) view engine in order to stream my views.

I am currently trying to extend [an example](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/examples/streaming-hoffman/app.js) provided by the official Dust.js repository.

Unfortunately I can't make it work with data retrieval using Mongoose.

**app.js**

```
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.engine('dust', hoffman.__express());

app.use(hoffman.stream);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.stream("hello", {
    "test": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
      //This works as expected
      //return [{name:"This is a name"},{name:"This is another name"}];

      return model.find().lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
              return docs;
            });
    },
    "test1": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
      return modelB.find(function(err, docs) {
              return docs;
            });
    }
  });
});
```

**hello.dust**

```
{#test}
  <br>{name}
{/test}

{#test1}
  <br>{name}
{/test1}
```

Comment: What is the output from `model.find()` ? If you log it or something. It's an array of documents?

Comment: Hello @Interrobang, happy new year.
My model returns an array  of documents.
e.g 

`[{
  _id: 5687 cf282018e4df73b62ea8,
  name: 'inserting 1451740968750',
  __v: 0
}, {
  _id: 5687 cf282018e4df73b62ea9,
  name: 'inserting 1451740968750',
  __v: 0
}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your usage of `.find`. The [Mongoose docs show that you must have a callback](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) that Mongoose will invoke with the documents, since `.find` is not synchronous.

You are returning the return value of `.exec`, which appears to be a Promise.

Looking at the Mongoose source, if you pass a callback to `.exec`, it will then [resolve the Promise with **nothing**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec):

```
if (!_this.op) {
  callback && callback(null, undefined);
  resolve();
  return;
}
```

You have a couple options to pass async data to dust via a helper. Firstly, you can return a Promise or Stream from your helper, which Dust will properly read. Mongoose offers [Query#stream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) for this purpose.

```
var stream = Thing.find({ name: /^hello/ }).stream();
```

Otherwise, you can manually render to the Dust `chunk` in the Mongoose callback:

```
"test": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  return chunk.map(function(chunk) {
    model.find().lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
      chunk.section(docs, context, bodies);
      chunk.end();
    });
  });
},
```

I don't use Mongoose, so if it has an option to do synchronous finds we can look into this more.

Comment: Hello there, lovely answer. I couldn't find any documentation pointing out how chunks are working.
Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: [Context Helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/) goes into detail about chunks. I think returning a Stream from the helper will be faster / easier for you, especially if you are using Hoffman streaming.

Comment: I had made it work, just a one more simple question is it possible to breakdown the stream and redirect my app to a 404 page if one of my functions had failed to execute?

Comment: If you emit an `error` event from the stream, Dust will abort rendering and render the `{:error}` block, if one exists. Since you've already begun streaming to the client, you can't issue a 301 or 302, but you could write a `meta` tag to redirect in the `{:error}` block.